# "No Signal" shows on LVDS display that is connected to HP T730

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport, thin-client

I have an HP T730 thin client which has 4 DisplayPort ports, I want to connect a 14-inch TFT display (BOE HB140WX1-100 LVDS interface) to a thin client, so I use a LVDS to HDMI converter (VS-TY2662-V1) and then a HDMI to DisplayPort converter to connect the display to thin client. the problem is that there is a "No Signal" message in the display and when I check the display setting in Windows in HP T730. there is a 640*480 resolution for the second display instead of 1366*768. I also connected the display to my PC which uses Intel Graphics 4000 and worked fine.

-HP T730 Graphics is AMD Radeon HD 9000
-HP T730 supports 4-displays simultaneously
-I installed the Graphics Driver (2016 and 2019)
-Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is installed on HP t730

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.